# Jquery trouble using .parent and .next

Tags: jquery

am doing a series of bios (of team members) and when bio is clicked the full bio is show using jquery .hide() and .show().

Here is the full js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/s0sjqzba/

Basically when each "Full Bio" button is clicked there is a reveal for that particular person, which then hides any other reveals hidden.

I tried this code

```
$( ".biobutton" ).click(function() {
      $(this).addClass("close").parent("biobutton").next().show( "slow");
});
```

My thinking is that when the button is clicked it would go to the parent div and find the next div (which is the reveal and show that.) but it's not working

Here is the html

```
<div class="row bio">
    <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x390">
    </div>
    <div class="medium-8 columns">
        <h3>
            Dr. Len Futerman, DDS
        </h3>
        <h4>
            Subheadline lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </h4>
        <p>
            Positive copy about the individual’s involvement about your treatment. Example: All of yourprocedures have one thing in common: they’ll be performed safely, painlessly and quickly by Dr. Len Futerman— Hampton Roads’ only dental anasthesiologist.
        </p>

    </div>
    <div class="medium-12 columns"><a href="#" class="biobutton"> FULL BIOGRAPHY</a></div>
</div>
<div class="specialreveal" style="min-width:100%; background-color:#333">
<div class="row" >
        <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <div class="medium-6 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        <div class="medium-4 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>



<div class="row bio">
    <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x390">
    </div>
    <div class="medium-8 columns">
        <h3>
            Dr. Len Futerman, DDS
        </h3>
        <h4>
            Subheadline lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </h4>
        <p>
            Positive copy about the individual’s involvement about your treatment. Example: All of yourprocedures have one thing in common: they’ll be performed safely, painlessly and quickly by Dr. Len Futerman— Hampton Roads’ only dental anasthesiologist.
        </p>

    </div>
    <div class="medium-12 columns"><a href="#" class="biobutton"> FULL BIOGRAPHY</a></div>
</div>
<div class="specialreveal" style="min-width:100%; background-color:#333">
<div class="row" >
        <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <div class="medium-6 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        <div class="medium-4 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `parent("biobutton")` should be `parent(".biobutton")` - You missed the `.` in the class selector.

Comment: Even then, your current HTML structure does not have any `.biobutton` with a parent that is again a `.biobutton`

Comment: make it a lot easier if you contain all elements for each `"module"` within a common parent. Then just traverse to that parent and use `find()` within the parent

Comment: ok, gotcha, I will try that thanks guys, I removed the biobutton and used parents and that made it work. Do I use siblings to find all other divs called special reveal and hide?

Comment: @charliefl how do I exclude the one that is being clicked on? I mean find() still applies to all

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```js
$(".specialreveal").hide();
$(".biobutton").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //here use preventDefault to stop page scroll to the top
    $(".specialreveal").hide(); //add this line to hide other open cv
    $(this).parents("div.row").next().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row bio">
    <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x390">
    </div>
    <div class="medium-8 columns">
         <h3>
   Dr. Len Futerman, DDS
  </h3>

         <h4>
   Subheadline lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </h4>

        <p>Positive copy about the individual’s involvement about your treatment. Example: All of yourprocedures have one thing in common: they’ll be performed safely, painlessly and quickly by Dr. Len Futerman— Hampton Roads’ only dental anasthesiologist.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-12 columns"><a href="#" class="biobutton"> FULL BIOGRAPHY</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="specialreveal" style="min-width:100%; background-color:#333">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-12 columns">
            <div class="medium-6 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
            <div class="medium-4 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row bio">
    <div class="medium-4 columns">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/450x390">
    </div>
    <div class="medium-8 columns">
         <h3>
   Dr. Len Futerman, DDS
  </h3>

         <h4>
   Subheadline lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </h4>

        <p>Positive copy about the individual’s involvement about your treatment. Example: All of yourprocedures have one thing in common: they’ll be performed safely, painlessly and quickly by Dr. Len Futerman— Hampton Roads’ only dental anasthesiologist.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-12 columns"><a href="#" class="biobutton"> FULL BIOGRAPHY</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="specialreveal" style="min-width:100%; background-color:#333">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="medium-12 columns">
            <div class="medium-6 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
            <div class="medium-4 columns">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**References**

[.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Comment: Thanks Alex, what did I do wrong there, other than the fade toggle, also how do I end up hiding any other reveals that are open?

Comment: Alex, I tried this, and it seems to work, what do you think, $( ".specialreveal" ).hide();
$( ".biobutton" ).click(function() {
        $( ".specialreveal" ).hide("slow");
      $(this).addClass("close").parents().next().show( "slow");

});

Comment: And please read document about jquery selector such `next` etc

Comment: K thanks!, only thing now is that when if I click an already open reveal it hides and shows it, is there an kill click function?

Comment: Is kinda hard with your current html layout. I tried lot of things to be honest. My opinion is to use my first example with `fadeToggle`. Isn't so important to close all other open cv's cause if user want to close them he always can click to the link.

Comment: ok that makes sense. How would the html need to change to accomplish this?

Comment: am trying this but no dice, I can't figure out how to exclude just "this"    $(".biowrapper" ).find( ".specialreveal" ).show();

        $(".biowrapper" ).find( ".specialreveal" ).not(this).hide();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63288/discussion-between-alex-char-and-deedub).